# Emulate Xbox 360 controller with mobile

Tags: xbox360, directinput, xinput

I'm developing an app for symbian phones to emulate an Xbox 360 controller.

I have made all the necessary connections, and I'm using `SendInput()` to emulate the mouse, because, AFAIK `SendInput` can only emulate keyboard and mouse. And I'm thinking of using the accelerometer of the mobile as an analog joystick to control pc. Do I have to write a driver or is there an api provided by microsoft?

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm looking into this thing right now. Did you ever find a solution? It seems that you have to create a virtual device driver which echoes commands, and then send commands to that virtual device for this to work...

Comment: No, I still haven't found a solution!